# Understanding ungrouping after using summarize() in dplyr R-package

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

I have a data frame with three variables. I group by 2 variables

```
gruppierter_df <- df |> 
  group_by(A, B)
```

Then I do:

```
gruppierter_df |> 
summarize(n=n())
```

which gives me an output including this message:

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'A'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
```

In the dplyr documentation it says, that after doing `summarize()` removes the right-hand side grouping variable.

I would expect, that after using `summarize()`, gruppierter_df is only grouped by "A". But if I use `summarize()` again it still gives the same output, where gruppierter_df is still grouped by the two variables "A" and "B".

I would have expected that the second `summarize()` would have given the same output as

```
gruppierter_df2 <- df |> 
  group_by(A)

gruppierter_df2 |> 
  summarize(n=n())
```

because the grouping by "B" would have been removed after using `summarize()` for the first time.

I would be happy if you could explain to me what exactly `summarize` does to the data frame.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't saving the result of `gruppierter_df |> summarize(n=n())` anywhere. If you did

```
x <- gruppierter_df |> summarize(n=n()); 
groups(gruppierter_df)
# [[1]]
# A
# [[2]]
# B
groups(x)
# [[1]]
# A
```

you'll see that groups only by A. Using `summarize` doesn't change `gruppierter_df` at all, it returns a new data.frame with different groups.

You'll see a different result if you do

```
gruppierter_df |> 
  summarize(n=n()) |> 
  summarize(n=n())
```